# Counting number of rows between rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with four columns: user_id, event, and time

User_id a user_id, event is either "A" or "B", and time is time. I need to count the number of "B" values that occur before each "A" value. So if there are 3 "B" values that occur before the first "A" then that instance of "A" will get a new column with a value of 3. If there are 25 instances of "B" before the next values of "A" then that will get a value of 25. I consider myself a solid R/dplyr journeyman but this has me stumped! Thanks.

```
user_id   event   date_time    desired_column
1         B       2018-01-01   NA
1         B       2018-01-02   NA
1         B       2018-01-03   NA
1         B       2018-01-04   NA
1         B       2018-01-05   NA
1         A       2018-01-06   5
1         B       2018-01-07   NA
1         A       2018-01-08   1
2         B       2018-01-05   NA
2         B       2018-01-06   NA
2         A       2018-01-07   2
2         B       ...          NA
2         A       ...          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
user_id   event   date_time    desired_column
1         B       2018-01-01   NA
1         B       2018-01-02   NA
1         B       2018-01-03   NA
1         B       2018-01-04   NA
1         B       2018-01-05   NA
1         A       2018-01-06   5
1         B       2018-01-07   NA
1         A       2018-01-08   1
2         B       2018-01-05   NA
2         B       2018-01-06   NA
2         A       2018-01-07   2')
```

Perhaps a little clunky, but ...

(**edit**: specified `dplyr::lag`, since `stats::lag` doesn't do what we need.)

```
x$a <- NA
x$a[cumsum(rle(x$event)$lengths)] <- rle(x$event)$lengths
x$a <- dplyr::lag(x$a)
x$a[x$event == "B"] <- NA

x
#    user_id event  date_time desired_column  a
# 1        1     B 2018-01-01             NA NA
# 2        1     B 2018-01-02             NA NA
# 3        1     B 2018-01-03             NA NA
# 4        1     B 2018-01-04             NA NA
# 5        1     B 2018-01-05             NA NA
# 6        1     A 2018-01-06              5  5
# 7        1     B 2018-01-07             NA NA
# 8        1     A 2018-01-08              1  1
# 9        2     B 2018-01-05             NA NA
# 10       2     B 2018-01-06             NA NA
# 11       2     A 2018-01-07              2  2
```

Comment: Thank you so much - as soon as I can submit my work I will try to figure out how you did this! My hero!

Comment: It's a trick of `rle` that I just happen to recall. I've never really used it in my day-to-day work, but happen to remember that it does counting like this pretty well. (Notice that it counts both A's and B's, which is why I had to clear out the B's. It also applies the count to the same letter, ergo `lag` needing to shift it to the next. There are almost certainly other ways to trick this out.)

Comment: For anyone attempting this solution, make sure you have lag assigned to dplyr and not base. I can see myself using this combination of cumsum and rle quite a bit; the next step is to build it into a function.

Answer (score 3):

Using @r2Evans' data :

```
x$y    <- NA
which_ <- which(x$event=="A")
x$y[which_] <- diff(c(0,which_))-1

#    user_id event  date_time desired_column  y
# 1        1     B 2018-01-01             NA NA
# 2        1     B 2018-01-02             NA NA
# 3        1     B 2018-01-03             NA NA
# 4        1     B 2018-01-04             NA NA
# 5        1     B 2018-01-05             NA NA
# 6        1     A 2018-01-06              5  5
# 7        1     B 2018-01-07             NA NA
# 8        1     A 2018-01-08              1  1
# 9        2     B 2018-01-05             NA NA
# 10       2     B 2018-01-06             NA NA
# 11       2     A 2018-01-07              2  2
```