# count number of B's between A's

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count how many B's i get before each A in my database.

Table like:

```
ID  -  value  -  datetime
10       A     2018-10-10 10:10:10
 9       B     2018-10-10 09:09:09
 8       B     2018-10-10 08:08:08
 7       B     2018-10-10 07:07:07
 6       B     2018-10-10 06:06:06
 5       A     2018-10-10 05:05:05
 4       B     2018-10-10 04:04:04
 3       B     2018-10-10 03:03:03
 2       B     2018-10-10 02:02:02
 1       A     2018-10-10 01:01:01
```

But would like to get a pull from the

```
ID  -         datetime   -    count 
10    2018-10-10 10:10:10      4
 5    2018-10-10 05:05:05      3
 1    2018-10-10 01:01:01      0
```

Something like: [Counting number of rows between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896367/counting-number-of-rows-between-rows)

**EDIT:**

With help from the answer I have modified it into my own table

```
SELECT a.ID
     , COALESCE(b.i,0) cnt
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MAX(y.ID) y_ID
         FROM tapdatabeer x         
         LEFT
         JOIN tapdatabeer y
           ON y.ID < x.ID
          AND y.beerstatus = '0'
        WHERE x.beerstatus = '1' AND x.beerline = 5 AND x.masterID = 4015
        GROUP 
           BY x.ID
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT ID
            , beerstatus            
            , CASE WHEN beerstatus = '0' then @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=0 END i 
         FROM tapdatabeer 
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        WHERE beerline = 5 AND masterID = 4015 
        ORDER 
           BY ID
     ) b
    ON b.ID = a.y_ID
```

I have manually checked that the result should be between 200 and 210 for each row here. 
The reason I'm getting this is because my ID's are not in a row, because there is also C's and D's in this table.
So many I need to create a custom counter for the query.
But my result is:

```
  ID    cnt
258991    0
265187    0
266442    0
272383    0
273134  206
277077    0
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: innodb_version
5.7.23-23
protocol_version
10 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I'm out :-(  ... this is a gaps and islands problem, and those are hard to handle without using analytic functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So that's a function i need version 8 and up to be able to do? Going to check with host if it' possible to run higher version

Comment: Yeah...if you have a serious long term need for this type of query, then do upgrade to MySQL 8.  If not, there are ways to do this with MySQL 5.7, but it's going to be ugly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i could consider placing my B's in another table when they come in. Think the query would look smoother.?

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,value CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('A');

SELECT a.id
     , COALESCE(b.i,0) cnt
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MAX(y.id) y_id
         FROM my_table x
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.id < x.id
          AND y.value = 'b'
        WHERE x.value = 'a'
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id
            , value
            , CASE WHEN value = 'b' then @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=0 END i 
         FROM my_table 
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.y_id;

+----+------+
| id | cnt  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    0 |
|  5 |    3 |
| 10 |    4 |
+----+------+
```

Comment: It works, but somehow i made it only work 1 out of 6 trying to use it on my own table. Will have a fresh look later.