# Count number of rows between two specific rows

Tags: r

The question is I want to count the number of rows between two rows that those two rows share some same value.

I found a question similar to me but the difference is I want to count the number of A after B in that question and group by id(may not be necessary, since in my data the beginning value will always be 0 for each id)
the link is here 
[Counting number of rows between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896367/counting-number-of-rows-between-rows)

Suppose I have data shows below

```
 a  <- data.frame(
    id     = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    visits = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0)
 )
```

and the output I want is

```
 a <- data.frame(
  id     = c(1, 1,  1, 1, 2,  2,  2, 2, 2), 
  visits = c(0, 0,  1, 0, 0,  1,  2, 0, 0), 
  z      = c(0, 1, NA, 0, 2, NA, NA, 0, 0)
 )
```

The value in the 3rd column could be NA or o or anything since I will move it so that is no problem. I want to count how many values larger than 0 are between two 0 value.

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what you are after from your output. What are events "A" and "B" here?  you want `z` to contain the number of non-zero values that occur before the next zero?

Comment: A, B just example from the question I found. For my data I want to  use z to count the number of non-zero values that occurs after a zero value. I hope this make my question clear, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this will do what you want

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(grp=cumsum(visits==0)) %>% 
  group_by(id, grp) %>% 
  mutate(z=ifelse(visits!=0, NA, sum(visits!=0))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% mutate(grp=NULL)
```

Here we "split" the data into zeros with runs of non zeros using `cumsum()` in the first mutate. Then we group by those runs, and create our variable by setting z to the number of non-zeros in each of those runs. Then finally we get rid of our temporary grouping variable.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in a more general setting than the existing answer, i.e. also add counts for repeating `1`'s and any other values. The last row per group is `NA` but that can be changed easily.

```
   a %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(
        c = map_dbl(
          seq_along(visits),
          ~ {
            m <- which(visits[.x] == visits[-seq(.x)])
            if (length(m) == 0) NA else min(m) - 1
          }
          )
        )

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id visits     c
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      0     0
2     1      0     1
3     1      1    NA
4     1      0    NA
5     2      0     2
6     2      1    NA
7     2      2    NA
8     2      0     0
9     2      0    NA
```