# Counting number of cases between two rows with a certain value by group

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to count the number of NAs that occur between a value and the last good value but grouping by two variables (plot and location). My data look similar to this:

```
df<-data.frame(year = seq(from = 2001, to = 2009, by = 1), 
               plot = rep(c('p_1','p_2'), each = 18, times = 1), 
               location = c(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 9, times = 2)),
               n = c(c(4,6,NA,8,9,NA,NA,NA,10), c(2,4,5,6,7,4,3,NA,NA)))
```

And the results should look something like this:

```
data.frame(year = seq(from = 2001, to = 2009, by = 1), 
               plot = rep(c('p_1','p_2'), each = 9, times = 2), 
               location = c(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 9, times = 2)),
               n = c(c(4,6,NA,8,9,NA,NA,NA,10), c(2,4,5,6,7,4,3,NA,NA)),
           count = c(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3), c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

I created a dummy variable called 'miss' with good values having a value of 0 and NAs a value of 1. Then I calculated the cumulative sum of those values but the resulting column is correct only for the first time a NA is encountered within the grouping and later it keeps adding all NAs in that combinaiton of location and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(miss = ifelse(is.na(n), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(plot, location) %>%
  summarize(plot = plot,
            location = location,
            year = year,
            n = n,
            count = dplyr::lag(cumsum(miss))+1) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count), -1, 
                      ifelse(is.na(n), 0,
                             count)))
 
data.frame(year = seq(from = 2001, to = 2009, by = 1), 
           plot = rep(c('p_1','p_2'), each = 9, times = 2), 
           location = c(rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 9, times = 2)),
           n = c(c(4,6,NA,8,9,NA,NA,NA,10), c(2,4,5,6,7,4,3,NA,NA)),
           count = c(NA,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                     NA,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))
```

I tried the suggestions in this post [Counting number of rows between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896367/counting-number-of-rows-between-rows) but I wasn't able to use the grouping function. That part is important because i my actual data I have a few hundred locations with several plots within them. Those anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: Added package tidyverse that I used in the sample.

Comment: can you explain, why the `NA` 's in rows 17 & 18, as well as the last 2 `NA`'s (rows 35 & 36) are not being counted in your proposed result data frame?

Comment: Hi. I am working with yearly count data, those NAs should not be counted because they are from the last years of those specific locations and plot. If I had another count value from year 2010 then those NAs would be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` solution. It uses an additional grouping variable to get the right `cumsum` boundaries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(l = cumsum(is.na(n) & is.na(n) != lag(is.na(n))), 
    plot, location) %>%
  mutate(count = replace_na(ifelse(lag(is.na(n)) & 
                   !is.na(n), sum(is.na(n)), 0), 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-l) %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
# A tibble: 36 × 5
    year plot  location     n count
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2001 p_1   A            4     0
 2  2002 p_1   A            6     0
 3  2003 p_1   A           NA     0
 4  2004 p_1   A            8     1
 5  2005 p_1   A            9     0
 6  2006 p_1   A           NA     0
 7  2007 p_1   A           NA     0
 8  2008 p_1   A           NA     0
 9  2009 p_1   A           10     3
10  2001 p_1   B            2     0
11  2002 p_1   B            4     0
12  2003 p_1   B            5     0
13  2004 p_1   B            6     0
14  2005 p_1   B            7     0
15  2006 p_1   B            4     0
16  2007 p_1   B            3     0
17  2008 p_1   B           NA     0
18  2009 p_1   B           NA     0
19  2001 p_2   A            4     0
20  2002 p_2   A            6     0
21  2003 p_2   A           NA     0
22  2004 p_2   A            8     1
23  2005 p_2   A            9     0
24  2006 p_2   A           NA     0
25  2007 p_2   A           NA     0
26  2008 p_2   A           NA     0
27  2009 p_2   A           10     3
28  2001 p_2   B            2     0
29  2002 p_2   B            4     0
30  2003 p_2   B            5     0
31  2004 p_2   B            6     0
32  2005 p_2   B            7     0
33  2006 p_2   B            4     0
34  2007 p_2   B            3     0
35  2008 p_2   B           NA     0
36  2009 p_2   B           NA     0
```